# App inventor/PHP app stopped working on Note 4's

Tags: php, android, mysql, app-inventor

We have been using an app that clocks our engineers in/out by connecting a mysql database and submitting values to it. From the 13th, the app appears to have stopped working on note 4's, but still works fine on the note 2's.

We were wondering if a firmware update has possibly stopped this app from working as we have been using this app with absolutely no issues until the 13th and it only seems to be affecting those who have note 4's?

[image: App Inventor Code]

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","***********","**********","appacmef_App");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$employeeid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['employeeid']);
$time = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['time']);
$longitude = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['longitude']);
$lattitude = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['lattitude']);
$vanreg = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['vanreg']);


$sql="INSERT INTO clockings (employeeid, time, longitude, lattitude, vanreg)
VALUES ('$employeeid', '$time', '$longitude', '$lattitude', '$vanreg')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *13th* ... looks like date format/parsing issue :) ... for example client app uses `dd-mm-yyyy` and server side `mm-dd-yyyy`

Comment: `pattern MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss`? mysql's date-as-string format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ssss`

Comment: I have just altered this now thanks, but unfortunately it hasn't solved the issue. How important is that Data format as it has been working for about half a year now?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you make even a single mistake. **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: [see also your forum thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/9w5FhTy69To/KGnVy5rgOjMJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the blocks and it now works again
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately there still is no error handling in your `Web.GotText` event, which means, an error will be ignored and you do not know why it did not work. And: using the new solution you only can transfer one booking to your server, but probably you only have one booking?